# Solve problem: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to mechanically `Solve[a y == (1 - a) x && u0 == x^a y^(1 - a),{x,y}]`, given 1>a>0 and u0>0.  The emphasis is on mechanically: I know it is simple in this case to do a log transform and get solution to the transformed system. I'd like a simple approach to the original system. I want only the positive real solution.

But `Solve` encounters a problem:

> Solve::incnst: "Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is x - a x - a y == 0."

Restricting the domain to Reals does not help.  As well as learning the proper approach to this problem, I would appreciate better understanding why the system is seen as inconsistent or redundant.

Comment: That is a weird ( and really incorrect ) error message.  The problem is that the system can only be solved for `a` in the specified range, but `Solve` has no mechanism to specify that restriction.

Comment: @belisarius Why can you make the assumption that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero and positive? Also, is it as a consequence of that assumption that you canceled out an $x$ factor in the first equation?

Comment: @belisarius Oh I see; no, I think you are right in that interpretation. I missed that in the OP. Nevertheless, when I try to use `Reduce` on the OP's expression (with the $x$ in the first equation), and adding your conditions, MMA churns and churns but doesn't really return a solution. Does it work on your side?

Comment: @MarcoB deleting comments. I pasted the equation wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're interested only in Real and positive solutions, the following will do:

```
eq = {a y == (1 - a) x && u0 == x^a y^(1 - a)};
assum = {y > 0 && x > 0 && 1 > a > 0};
s0 = Solve[eq[[1, 1]], x];
sy = Solve[FullSimplify[eq[[1, 2]] /. s0[[1]], Assumptions -> assum], y];
js = Join[s0 /. sy, sy] // Flatten

(* {x -> -(((-1 + a^-1)^a a u0)/(-1 + a)), 
    y ->    (-1 + a^-1)^a u0}
*)
```

Comment: @Alan Check it now, please

Comment: Although this is not quite as "mechanical" as I hoped, it gets me there without explicit transformation of the functional form.  The key was the `FullSimplify` after the substitution.  Thanks.  I recommend editing so that `eq` and `assum` are not lists, so you won't need multiple indexes for `Part`.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Thanks! As you know, in this site you can edit other people's posts if you find it convenient!